# How can I fix this error while deploying my bot unto heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord

I was trying to deploy a bot onto heroku and I followed someone's tutorial. I thought I did everything correctly but it says that my push failed. Can someone help? Full error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

For my build packs i installed python because thats what I use and here is my main code:

```py
import discord import os
 
client = discord.Client()
 
@client.event async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
 
client.run(os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN'])
```

I also have a requirements file which just has one line with "discord" on it
Finally, i have a procfile:

> worker: python main.py

Answer (score 0):

by default it's try to build it on highest version available.
make sure it's ok for and if not define version in runtime.txt.

also in my experience I was need to add uwsgi to the requirement file.